# Difference between port 3000 and 3001 in a fresh react-fullstack generated project?

Tags: reactjs, react-fullstack

I just run react-fullstack generator, and got two identical servers running at port 3000 and 3001.

A quick google found that the 3001 port is supposed to be a webpack-dev-server.
But the actual content I see at 3000 and 3001 is identical!

What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Maybe you're serving a webpack-dev-server + another express or something and they each take their own port?

Comment: https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/ so 3000 is the webpack dev server and 3001 the API server.

Comment: Not sure, I just created a fresh project using https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-react-fullstack, and got identical webpages on 3000 and 3001.